# Two different sized colonies from the same species of bacteria. What does it mean?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, cell-culture

I have got two different sized colonies in a plate of Salmonella Paratyphi, identified by biochemical methods. What does two different sized colonies mean? What kind of question can I investigate in this regard?

Protocol followed:

Positivity of serum sample was checked in BacT/Alert blood culture system. Bacteria was subcultured from the positive result giving culture bottle from the BacT/Alert system and incubated overnight at 35 degree celsius. Two different sized colonies were found and they were subjected to biochemical and antisera tests and both identified as Salmonella Paratyphi.

Comment: Could you please add details about the protocol you followed ?

Comment: @MauroM Some details added

Comment: Do you happen to have an image of your plate?

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAbdullah ! Unfortunately i'm not expert enough to solve your doubts; the only thing that i can think is that the founders of the two colonies reacted to the culture environment differently e.g. the founder of the bigger colony was more rapid to adapt and divided more rapidly compared to the other... I would try to made another culture (exactly same conditions) to see if the size difference persists and then investigate the genomes of the two colonies even if i'm not sure wich technique to use since i'm not a microbiology expert.

Comment: @Chris Sorry I am away from lab for couple of days. When I return I'll try to manage a picture.

Comment: @MauroM thanks for you suggestion. I'll try along this line.

Comment: You're welcome @AhmedAbdullah !

Comment: It could be thousands of things, but only a few of them will persist if you keep subculturing both colonies. Happily those are the interesting things, so if you subculture both colonies and they're the same size it was probably something as boring as 'two bacteria stuck together, giving one colony an edge'. If they're still different sizes, report back! Something interesting has happened.

Comment: How different are the colonies in size? This could also be a result of human error while plating. You should repeat these experiments and measure the statistics and if the trend is consistent then consider looking for a reason.